# Entity Framework relationship between same object

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am encountering a problem with a web API I'm developing. In my application, I have an object named "Process," and there is a relationship where one process can be a prerequisite for another process. To manage this relationship, I've created another object named "ProcessPreReq."

The issue arises when I attempt to update a "Process" by adding or removing a "ProcessPreReq" through the API. The database doesn't get updated correctly:

1. **Removal Problem:** When I try to remove a "ProcessPreReq" from a "Process," the API doesn't remove the relationship, and the data remains unchanged.
2. **Duplication Issue:** If I attempt to "re-add" a relationship that was previously removed, it duplicates the record in the database instead of simply reestablishing the relationship.

I've already performed migrations and updated the database, but the problem persists.

I'm using Entity Framework or a similar ORM, and I'd appreciate any insights, advice, or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and ensure that the database updates correctly when managing the "Process" and "ProcessPreReq" relationships.

Here's a simplified example of the code structure I'm using:

```
public class Process
{
    public int ProcessId { get; set; }
    // Other properties

    public ICollection<ProcessPreReq> ProcessPreReqs { get; set; }
}

public class ProcessPreReq
{
    public int ProcessPreReqId { get; set; }
    public int ProcessId { get; set; } // Foreign key
    public int PrerequisiteProcessId { get; set; } // Foreign key
    // Other properties

    public Process Process { get; set; }
    public Process PrerequisiteProcess { get; set; }
}

CONTEXT:
 builder.Entity<ProcessPreReq>()
                .HasOne(pp => pp.Process)
                .WithMany(p => p.PreReqProcesses)
                .HasForeignKey(pp => pp.ProcessId);

 builder.Entity<ProcessPreReq>()
                .HasOne(pp => pp.PreReqProcess)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(pp => pp.PreReqProcessId);
```

If you need to see more code or configurations, please let me know. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

I tried to update a "Process" entity by adding or removing a related "ProcessPreReq" entity through my web API.

Expectation:
My expectation was that when I removed a "ProcessPreReq," it would not only be dissociated from the "Process" but also be completely deleted from the "ProcessPreReq" table in the database. Furthermore, when I added it again, it should create a new relationship without duplicating the record.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ChangeTracker to identify and mark your child as deleted.

```
using var context = new ProcessContext();

var process = context.Process.Include(e => e.ProcessPreReqs).First(e => e.Name == ".NET");

// Mark an existing ProcessPreReqs as Deleted
var ProcessPreReqsforDelete = process.ProcessPreReqs.Single(e => e.Title == "Item to delete ProcessPreReqs");
context.Remove(ProcessPreReqsforDelete);

context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
Console.WriteLine(context.ChangeTracker.DebugView.LongView);

context.SaveChanges();
```

for more visit [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/)